# How can I position some elements precisely?

Tags: transforms

How can I place these arches I made around a center (for example, the origin), in order to make all of them perfectly aligned to X,Y,Z?

Thank you in advance to the kind users

[image]

Comment: It seems to me, the more interesting question here is how you place them not in a straight line with the array modifier... Maybe the object has some rotation? What happens if you hit Alt+R to reset rotation?

Answer (score 1):

There are probably hundreds of ways to align objects in Blender. One easy way to align objects that have their origin points in the centers(if you have objects rotated 180° facing each other) would be to scale them to 0 using Affect Only Locations while constrained to desired axis. If you set origin to bounds center before this, it ensures the origins are at centers(this will align origins so it matters where they are). Transform pivot point must not be set to Individual Origins for this to work. It can be any other transform pivot point mode that happens to be convenient for you.

[image]

Of course since all transform operators(like <kbd>G</kbd>,<kbd>R</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>) take [precise numerical inputs](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/transform/control/numeric_input.html) or you can use Mirror or Array modifiers it might make sense to place the objects precisely in the first place in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Empty` for that. Create one with `Add > Empty > Plain Axes` (or another one there) and make it the parent of your arch arrays. Their transforms will be local to the empty now, so you can enter <s>precise</s> convenient offset values (in my example its `(3,0,0)`, `(-3,0,0)`, `(0,3,0)`, `(0,-3,0)`. You can now transform the empty freely and the arches will keep their relative positions.

[image]

If you know all your arches will have the same layout you can also use a combination of an `Empty` and the `Mirror` modifier. Create an `Empty` again, but this time you need only one arch array and do not need to parent it. Align it with the `Empty` to your wished offset, add an `Mirror` modifier with `X` and `Y` activated and set the `Empty` as the mirror object. Now rotate the `Empty` 45° around the z-axis. This version keeps you from the hassle to maintain four array copies but obviously it will constrain you to offset them individually.

[image]

Comment: Why is the empty needed here?

Comment: I dont get your question, why not? I also explained the advantages, its very useful.

Comment: You don't need an empty to enter precise values. "Their transforms will be local to the empty now, so you can enter precise offset values (in my example its (3,0,0), (-3,0,0), (0,3,0), (0,-3,0)." If you enter precise values during transformations in the first place, what does it matter if they are parented to something or not? You can use an empty for mirror modifier or array with object offset, but why do you need it to just precisely transform objects?.. You don't.

Comment: I did not claim its needed, you may have misunderstood that. OP asked how to align them around "some center", so i showed him an option with local offsets which i believe is more convienient than juggling objects around globally.

Comment: No need for juggling objects around. There is absolutely no need to use an empty to just change transformation pivot point. Transform Pivot Point settings are for that. You can place 3dCursor in the center... I am not sure I follow...

Comment: I guess its just about workflow, like you said there are hundreds of ways. To me, an empty is just like a "conserved 3D cursor". Very useful to organise parts of the scene to have them ready for further editing/modeling. In a big scene (a complex skyscraper for example) i wouldn't like to have a bunch of global objects and re-center the 3D cursor all the time to refine. I just believe the OP's question intention is in that direction, your answer is also perfectly fine if that fits his needs.